# How can I make my code to find the minimum faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, min, execution

I have a question about how to find minimum in a list in my way:

I have a large list where every record is like this:

```
['22:00:19', '0026f88e557225333f01', '23', '37', '', '176.2', '0', '60', 'SOMETHING', 
 3.318717958567554e-05]
```

But the first and the last records in the list don't contain the last number:

For example:

```
['22:00:09', '0026f88e557225333f01', '23', '37', '', '176', '0', '60', 'SOMETHING']
```

I need to find the min of that last column `3.318717958567554e-05` and its index in every call of my function.

Here is my code:

```
def find_min(data, size, num):

    for index, i in enumerate(data):

        if index == 0 or index == data.__len__() -1: continue

        if index == 1:
            minimum = float(i[9])
            idx = index
            continue

        if float(i[9]) < minimum or float(i[9]) < num:
            minimum = float(i[9])
            idx = index

    return idx, minimum
```

`num` is a user-defined threshold which is used to calculate min. (Min should be less than that.)
This code works properly and I find what I want but how can I make my code faster because I call this function thousand times and I work with a huge dataset and as a result the execution time is very much because of that slow function.

Comment: dont use __len__() - use `len(data)`

Comment: If this is your main bottleneck, consider sorting or indexing your data in such a way to optimize for being able to find this answer _quickly_, without a full scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all the `if` statements and slice the array to just the ones you care about.

Convert `i[9]` to float just once.

```
def find_min(data, size, num):
    idx = 1
    minimum = float(data[1][9])
    for index, i in enumerate(data[2:-1]):        
        f = float(i[9])
        if f < minimum or f < num:
            minimum = f
            idx = index + 2 # +2 because of the slicing
    
    return idx, minimum
```

Or if the list is so large that making a slice of it is too expensive, just iterate over indexes:

```
def find_min(data, size, num):
    idx = 1
    minimum = float(data[1][9])
    for index in range(2, len(data)-1):     
        f = float(data[index][9])
        if f < minimum or f < num:
            minimum = f
            idx = index
    
    return idx, minimum
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your second solution helped me!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `minimum = float(data[1][9])`?

Comment: Also, instead of iterating over a `range` and indexing into the list, it will almost certainly be faster to just iterate over it directly, `for row in data:` and then `try: f = float(row[9]) except IndexError: continue`

Comment: Benchmarking would be necessary to confirm, but I think indexing is fast.